# Replicating the CMOS contents from one PC to many others

Tags: c++, windows, automation, bios

We have about 100 PCs of the same brand and model manufactured in 2010. I need to change in all these PCs, periodically and manually, the system and user passwords through the BIOS and would like to automate this procedure through a software and had the following idea:

The motherboard manufacturer sent me a program to read and write the CMOS. I starts with the setting up these passwords on a single PC, saving all your content to a file and after with this program, I write de CMOS to the others machines. Detail: this program is to be used with a boot disk with DOS.

As I would like to carry this procedure through the central server, copying the file with new CMOS data to a specific folder existent on all machines. In each PC there is a process running on Windows XP SP3 that as soon as received the file, make the reading the contents, writing the new passwords in its CMOS, deletes the file from the folder and restarts yourself. The theory should work, but not, inclusive on the same machine where I created the file. What happens is that every time I update the CMOS, the changed settings are retained, but the passwords always come back clean, i.e. without any protection to access to BIOS.

Now I'm basing my work on one program called CmosPwd which can be found on the site www.cgsecurity.org, but no options works properly on the motherboard that we have. Our platform apparently uses the Award BIOS 6.00 PG as base to these chinese mother boards. Tried new contact with the manufacturer, but they do not provide a map of the structure of the CMOS. I discovered that, comparing the various files, passwords are not written in ASCII mode only 5 bytes at offset 0x40, that I believe to be your CRC, as showed below:

```
CMOS DUMP WITH PASSWORDS:

SYSTEM: 11111111
USER  : 22222222

CMOS Bank 0:
    00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
    -----------------------------------------------
 0: 59 00 55 00 14 00 05 02 05 13 26 02 40 80 08 00 
 1: 40 f0 00 00 02 80 02 00 04 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 2: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fc 
 3: 00 04 20 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 4: **59 00 55 00 14 00** 05 02 05 13 26 02 40 80 08 00 
 5: 40 f0 00 00 02 80 02 00 04 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 6: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fc 
 7: 00 04 20 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

CMOS Bank 1:
    00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
    -----------------------------------------------
 0: 59 00 55 00 14 00 05 02 05 13 26 02 40 80 08 00 
 1: 40 f0 00 00 02 80 02 00 04 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 2: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fc 
 3: 00 04 20 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 4: **59 00 55 00 14 00** 05 02 05 13 26 02 40 80 08 00 
 5: 40 f0 00 00 02 80 02 00 04 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 6: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fc 
 7: 00 04 20 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

SYSTEM: AAAAAAAA
    USER  : BBBBBBBB

```
 CMOS Bank 0:
    00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
    -----------------------------------------------
 0: 51 00 01 00 15 00 05 02 05 13 26 02 00 80 08 00 
 1: 40 f0 00 00 02 80 02 00 04 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 2: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fc 
 3: 00 04 20 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 4: **51 00 01 00 15 00** 05 02 05 13 26 02 40 80 08 00 
 5: 40 f0 00 00 02 80 02 00 04 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 6: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fc 
 7: 00 04 20 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

CMOS Bank 1:
    00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
    -----------------------------------------------
 0: 51 00 01 00 15 00 05 02 05 13 26 02 40 80 08 00 
 1: 40 f0 00 00 02 80 02 00 04 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 2: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fc 
 3: 00 04 20 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 4: **51 00 01 00 15 00** 05 02 05 13 26 02 40 80 08 00 
 5: 40 f0 00 00 02 80 02 00 04 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 
 6: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 fc 
 7: 00 04 20 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Has anyone had a problem about this and got a simple and cheap solution, or would have any hint to this? I appreciate some any kind of help.

Comment: This is, at best, very risky. Even if the computers are from the same maker, the same model and even manufactured in the same year, doesn't mean that their hardware will be _exactly_ the same or have the _exact_ same version of the BIOS.

Comment: Hi Joachim. Thanks for your reply. Yes, I agree with you. But in my tests, at worst, I get a BIOS error message (F1 to continue with default values).  Our machines have no specific configuration for the BIOS (all are in factory default, except for passwords), If I get the solution to keep passwords inside CMOS, and if run in 70% of total, my manual work will be reduced only to 30% and I'll have more time to research.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to keep in mind:

- In most modern chipsets, there are multiple banks of CMOS bytes beyond the core 70h/71h that you are reading now.  Look in the datasheet for your chipset and read about "extended CMOS".  Its exact implementation varies from chipset to chipset, but it is likely at 72h/73h.  This is probably your issue.
- For a modern UEFI BIOS, the contents of CMOS are simply there for legacy compatibility.  The "real" BIOS settings are stored in the BIOS flash chip.
- Joachim Pileborg is correct.  The internal structure of the CMOS bits changes from revision to revision of the BIOS.  It is pretty much guaranteed to not be portable between different motherboards.  And it may not be portable between BIOS revs.  For this to work reliably, all motherboards should be identical, with identical BIOS versions.